# Window click event to fire before button click event

Tags: javascript, events, dojo

I have two components with event listeners set up, one is a menu component and the other is a button. When the button is clicked, I want the menu to close *before* the button's onClick function is fired, however the order of events is currently:

1) Button is clicked

2) Button's onclick is fired

3) Menu's onWindow click event is fired

The setup for both is below:

The button:

```
    <button class="sos-btn sos-btn-confirm" data-dojo-attach-event="click: _apply">Apply Filters</button>
```

The menu:

```
    _createEventListeners: function() {
        this.clickListener = on.pausable(
            window,
            'click',
            this._onWindowClick.bind(this)
        );

        this.clickListener.pause();
    },

    _onWindowClick: function(e) {
        if(!this.domNode.parentNode.contains(e.target)) {
            this.close();
        }
    },
```

The button click handler:

```
        _apply: function(e) {
            // do things
        }
```

The problem here is that I need the menu to have closed before the button's event handler is ran, so I'd like the order to be:

1) Button is clicked

2) Menu's onWindow click event is fired

3) Button's onclick is fired

I don't mind if I need to put something at the top of the `_apply` function to bubble the event immediately, I'm just not sure how to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: I've just tried to wrap the whole _apply function in a setTimeout to remove it from the main thread and that's done the trick, but I wonder if there's a more elegant approach.

Comment: copy the code for closing the menu and paste it to the top of  button click event

Comment: They're two completely separate modules and I don't want to couple them together like that. @eomer